# Power Automate to alert if file NOT created, Condition on length of array

Tags: conditional-statements, azure-logic-apps, string-length, power-automate

I'm using the below to check if a file has been created in a folder. If it hasn't been done someone's forgotten and we need an alert.
Listing the folder, and the two filters give the results I'd expect. The FilterTimes uses Addhours/UTCNow(-ve) so only files newer than the threshold make it through.

However, if there are no new files, the output of the last filter is Body[] as expected, but when this get passed to the condition, I'm just getting the input of that being { "expressionResult": false}

I think I'm getting my brackets and commas wrong in the condition, or have I named the array incorrectly?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please input expression `length(body('FilterTimes'))` to the left input box of "**Condition**" but not input the string `length(body('FilterTimes'))` to the box. The string `length(body('FilterTimes'))` doesn't equal to `0`, so the result is `false`.

I do the same steps in my power automate, it works fine if I input the expression.

[image]